# The LINQ query returns the same record in the list

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm having trouble with a LINQ query that returns the same record in a list but only in the application. The same query in LINQPAD returns the correct results, does anyone have any idea why?

```
public IEnumerable<TireMasterProcess> GetAllComponentParameter(string productionCode, 
    string revisionNo, string fieldName, string[] fieldNames)
{
    var isExists = false;

    using (var dbContext = new TireMasterProcessDbContext())
    {
        isExists = (
            from t2 in dbContext.Processes
            where
                t2.ProductionCode.Trim() == productionCode && 
                t2.RevisionNo.Trim() == revisionNo &&
                t2.FieldName.Trim() == fieldName
            select t2.DataChr.Trim()
            )
            .FirstOrDefault() != null;

        return (
            from t in dbContext.Processes
            where
                t.ProductionCode.Trim() == "FP08" && 
                t.RevisionNo.Trim() == "102" &&
                (new string[] {"B2-BiasLR", "B2-Fabric"}).Any(f => 
                    t.FieldName.Trim().Equals(f)) && 
                isExists
            orderby t.FieldName ascending
            select t
            )
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this mean exactly "*that returns the same record in a list*", are you sure its pointing to the same database?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.This means that the result returned in the application is a list with the correct number of items, but each item is the same. It looks like LINQ has created a list of the correct size and duplicated the same record in it.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the described issue isn't caused by the code that uses the result of `GetAllComponentParameter`

Comment: What is the source of `dbContext.Processes` in database - table or view? Is configured PK correct(unique)?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure:
`var collectionB2 = dbContext.GetAllComponentParameter(
                ProductionCode, RevisionNo, "B2-PartNo", new string[] { "B2-BiasLR", "B2-Fabric" });`

@IvanStoev the table does not have PK

Comment: Why do you trim all your columns all the time?

Comment: This question needs a [mcve]

Comment: @michaelrandall this question needs your first question answering.. I've got no idea what *"LINQ query that returns the same record in a list"* actually means

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you for your help. The problem is that there is no primary key in the table, I used more unique columns.

Comment: The duplicate is about views, but the explanation applies.